# pipe and uppipe in nodejs when handling incoming post request

Tags: node.js

Considering the following code, using nodejs 0.10.22, and expressjs 3.x

```
app.post('/upload', function(req,res){

    var size = 0;
    var writable = fs.createWriteStream('./example.file');

    req.pipe(writable);
    req.on('data', function(data){
        size += data.length;
        if (size > 1048576) {
            req.unpipe();
            //writable = null;
        }
    })

    res.send('end');
});
```

When users upload some data (e.g. a file), a WriteStream is created to save the data

In order to limit the amount of data saved to the hard drive, I have a listener for 'data'. When the size > 1 Mb, I call req.unpipe() to stop the piping.

However, req keeps piping into the writable and at the end, example.file will be as large as the uploaded file. Even if I nullify the writable by calling writable = null, req.pipe() keeps piping all the data to example.file

Is there something wrong with my code or is this a bug with the stream.readable.pipe() method?

Comment: Checked your code and it seems to work ok

Comment: Is the size of the file you're testing with smaller than 1114112?

Comment: I think the code would work, but it doesn't. I tried a file of 2 Mb and a file of 10 Mb. Forgot to mention, I am using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your "/upload" route before `express.bodyParser()` if you're using it.

Comment: I did not use express.bodyParser() because the multipart() inside the bodyParser() is being phased out in the next version of connect.
I am trying to understand nodejs with minimum abstraction. By the way, even if I use: http.createServer(function(req,res){ /*piping code here */ }), the req.pipe() still keeps piping when the size > 1 Mb